# Unable to upload files with FF Matrix 1.3.5

Tags: matrix, file-uploads, ee1, fieldtype

All fields using the FF Matrix fieldtype (version 1.3.5) have suddently stopped working. My client can no longer upload files, and the fields can no longer be expanded to add new rows.

This is an old but very active site using EE 1.6.8 build 20100121. The FF Matrix fields are the heart of the site, and my client reports that they were working fine until yesterday.

Is this a known issue? Is there an update to FF Matrix that is compatible with EE 1.6.8 which could fix the problem? Or some other fix?

Brian

Comment: What changed on your server? I'd inquire with your host - maybe a change in your PHP version? Nothing "suddenly stops working" without a reason!

Comment: Derek, you're right that nothing just stops working for no reason. I thought the client may have updated or changed something the caused a conflict (I don't maintain the site regularly), but they say no. So you're right that the next place to look is to the host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the host look at the /tmp directory for your hosting account. It might be full or permissions may have changed.

Also, look at your php logs. If there is a specific PHP error stopping the upload, it might be there.

Also, look at the actual hosting account's diskspace. Maybe you've hit your limit.

Comment: Thanks, Anna. It's not a diskspace issue, and I don't see anything relevant in the PHP logs, so I will ask the host about the /tmp directory.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, @Anna_MediaGirl and Derek. We've continued to explore this issue. The host says there have been no PHP changes and no PHP errors have appeared. Now it appears to be browser-specific: my client can upload files correctly using Firefox on Windows, but all other browsers that we've tested, on Mac and Windows, including Chrome, Safari, Opera, and IE, show the error and don't allow uploads. I'm out of ideas. Does anyone have any additional thoughts?

Comment: Are you seeing JS errors in the console?

Comment: Anna, yes, thanks for the suggestion. The console revealed some errors that allowed me to track down the problem. The hosting company recently migrated the site to a new server, and several file paths were still directed to the old server's IP address. The problem appears to be fixed. Thanks again!

Comment: Perfect! Please select my answer as correct by clicking the check mark above if it helped.